# How to get resized downloadUrl (Firebase Resize Images extension NEW Version 0.1.10)

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, resize-image, firebase-extensions

> Version 0.1.10 fixed - A fresh token is now generated for each resized
> image. (Issue #323, PR #351)
> [Link to PR #351](https://github.com/firebase/extensions/pull/351/files)

```
const img = await storageRef.child(pathname).put(sampleImg);
const imgDownloadUrl = await img.ref.getDownloadURL();
```

imgDownloadUrl will return the old NON resized image. I need access to the resized _200x200 image

Comment: Cloud Storage path for resized images: A relative path in which to store resized images. For example, if you specify a path here of thumbs and you upload an image to /images/original.jpg, then the resized image is stored at /images/thumbs/original_200x200.jpg

Comment: @frunkad but how long to wait if downloading client-side